# Xcode memory profiler ARC disable

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I developed OSX project in objective-c. I disabled ARC and I dealloc(release) memory manually. Is in xcode any tool, which can show me that I forget release any objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays i would recommend using ARC. But back then, when it wasn't available,  the Profiler "Leaks" Tool did a pretty good job for me. You can see total allocations and potential leaks there. 
You can start it by clicking Product --> Profile --> Leaks . 
That's doing a analysis on runtime. 
The Product --> Analyse Tool can analyse your code statically and show up further potential leaks (The arrows it draws can be a little confusing at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Profile menu item in Xcode and select the [Leaks instrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Instrument-Leaks.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Instrument for that.

XCode-->Open Developer Tool-->Instrument.

Check out :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html

and

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/